# Can Liferay publish to a another server?

Tags: jsp, web, liferay, portal, multiserver

here is the third question of my liferay series. :-) Sorry therefore but it is a different question.

I want to provide a service on my server for sport clubs. The clubs should use the system for managing their internal communication. Furthermore they should publish news, content, etc. for all their guests on the public website. To get the full benefit the club must to transfer its domain to my server. To avoid this I thought of publishing to a different server. For example: The club uses my system for internal communication. If the club wants to change public content they can change it in my system and publish it then to their own server.

The other solution would be to distribute my system to all the clubs. In this case every club needs a server with a java vm. :-(

**I want to combine the portal and the website of these clubs.** Does anybody has an idea?

Thank you very much.

---

Every club on one physical machine is impossible for me. Imagine a website of a huge sports club. If I transfer the domain to my server I have to admin all his email addresses and so on. :-(

So I am searching for a solution to host my portal (the internal part) on my Server and the external parts (public websites) on the server of the clubs. I thought of a syncing mechanism. So I could sync the public site to the club server. But I think it wouldn't work because the public liferay sites needs also a JVM. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at Staging: This is available locally (same server, easy testing for the scenario you outline above) and remotely, where you have one server that you use to set up all the content and a production server that gets the data from the editorial staging server. It's documented in [this chapter](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/field-type-variable-name) (scroll down a bit)

Answer (score 0):

Liferay provides feature of portal instances and portal sites. Within single lifeary server, you can create many portal instances and sites.

In your case, you can create different sites for different sports club. All sports club will have that scope for their content.

Member of sports club will have their own announcement, message board, calendar etc.

Also, there can be common areas which will be available for guests.

Also, please look at [WSRP](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/WSRP) for distributed architecture for portal.

Hope this helps

Comment: I would add that you can set a different domain for each site so the club's address remains unchanged, but all clubs would run on one physical machine and you have to manage only one server.

Comment: But there is no solution to avoid a transfer of an existing domain, or? Every club has to transfer their domain to my hoster or have to link to there liferay site. I cannot split up the public area and the private area to different servers?

Comment: edited my answer, added a link, please have a look and you can design this!